# Understanding the use of true/false for boolean in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I need some help understanding a part of a Kotlin course that Im watching and Im a complete beginner in coding.

So at some point the instructor creates a class called "Loot" and he wants to make it a property of another class called "Player".

He defines the property as

`val inventory = arrayList<Loot>()`

in "Player" class and now he wants to create a function to remove items from "inventory" and also overload that function with different parameters.

This is how he writes the code for those 2 functions called "dropLoot"

```
fun dropLoot(item: Loot): Boolean {
    return if (inventory.contains(item)) {
        inventory.remove(item)
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

fun dropLoot(name: String): Boolean {
    return inventory.removeIf { it.name == name }
}
```

Now my questions is, why did he write those `true`/`false` codes the first time he creates the function but not the second time?
And in both forms the functions do return true or false depending on result of the condition.

What does `true`/`false` mean and can I remove it from the first function with no change in my final result?

Comment: `return inventory.remove(...)` should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can only speculate at what the author was thinking.

The behavior of these two functions is not the same. The first function will remove only one item, even if it appears in the list multiple times. The second function will remove *all* items with that name.

The first function has been overcomplicated. The `list.remove()` function already returns a Boolean telling you whether there was actually an item to remove that was removed, so it could be written as the following and have an identical result:

```
fun dropLoot(item: Loot): Boolean {
    return inventory.remove(item)
}
```

so you are right that it could be written similarly to how the second function is written.

But if we imagined that the `remove()` function did not return a Boolean and you aren't allowed to call `remove()` safely until you first confirm if the item is available to remove, then the code would actually make sense.

Incidentally, the second function should use `removeAll` instead of `removeIf`. The end result will be the same, but `removeAll` is the Kotlin-specific way to do it and is theoretically better performing than Java's `removeIf` (though in practice the difference is negligible in most cases).

Comment: May be worth highlighting that we can infer the meaning of the return value from both functions: _it indicates whether anything was changed as a result_. (Ideally, that would be specified explicitly in a `/** ... **/` comment before each function; but that's the same behaviour as many standard library functions, so it's not a surprise if you know them.)

Answer (score 0):

`if` is an *expression* - each branch returns a value, which is the last value expressed in that block. So in the first example, each branch is explicitly expressing a final value (a `Boolean`), and that's what's getting returned. In the second example, `removeIf` also evaluates to a final `Boolean` value (i.e. it returns one as a result of the call), and that's what gets returned.

Basically, in the first example the author is returning *true* or *false* depending on which branch gets executed, so those values have to be expressed as the last thing in each branch. The second one could be written like this:

```
return if (inventory.removeIf { it.name == name }) {
    true
} else {
    false
}
```

But that's redundant since you're doing nothing in the *if/else* besides expressing the result of the condition check - if *condition* is *true*, return *true*, but if *condition* is *false*, return *false*. You may as well just return *condition* as-is!

The first example is a little different, because you're doing some work before returning a value, so you can't just return the result of the condition check -you have to check, do the work, then return the result. You *could* check it again instead of explicitly saying *true* or *false*, but the latter is clearer - plus it's possible that the condition check would give a different result if you call the same thing again! So in this case, the author is saying *"if we're in this branch, the result is true"* etc.

---

As *Tenfour04* points out, `remove()` already effectively does a `contains()` check, and returns *true* or *false* depending on whether the item existed to be removed. So it could be shortened to

```
return inventory.remove(item)
```

But you might see this explicit *true/false* pattern more generally (although this isn't the only way to write that kind of logic)

Also, *lambda expressions* are also expressions (I mean it's in the name!) which means this

```
{ it.name == name }
```

is itself an expression - it compares the two values, and either evaluates to *true* or *false*. And because it's the last expression in the lambda, that's the final value. In this case, that final value is used to decide whether to remove the item the lambda was run on. You'll see this with other stuff, e.g. `map` which transforms items into something else. Whatever the last expressed value (result) of the `map` function, that's what the item is transformed into. Or you can make a list like this:

```
val myList = List(10) { "hi" }
```

The lambda there is used to generate values for each item in the list - the index of each item is passed in as `it`, if you want to use it. I'm just expressing `"hi"` each time, so that's the value each item in the list gets set to. Hopefully you get the idea at this point!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, a bit complicated for my current level of knowledge, but very informative.